# Create hyper link to a pdf page in shiny app

Tags: hyperlink, shiny, rstudio

How to create a hyperlink to a specific page of pdf in sihny application?

I have title of a tabPanel in shiny. My objective is to create a hyperlink which takes to a specific page of a pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
a("Page4",target="_blank",href="myfile.pdf#page=4")
```